# how to find the number of dictionaries with a particular value in an array of dictionaries?

Tags: python

I have an array of dictionaries that look like

```
a = [
  {'name': 'a', 'age':10},
  {'name': 'b', 'age':10},
  {'name': 'c', 'age':15},
  {'name': 'd', 'age':10}
]
```

I want to find the number of items in this array that have "`age`" of `10`. I am looking for an one line solution with `len` and `set` (I want to avoid using for loop). Thanks.

=================

What if I want to find the number of unique "age"s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For count:

```
len(list(filter(lambda x: x['age'] == 10, a)))
```

For unique:

```
len(set(map(lambda x: x['age'], a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`len([x for x in lst if x['age'] == 10])`

Answer (score 0):

You cause `len()` with a list comprehension -

```
len([item for item in lst if item['age'] == 10])
```

Technically this is still a for loop, but would be a bit faster than the conventional `for` loops in Python.

Example run -

```
>>> lst = [{'name': 'a',
... 'age':10
... },
... {'name': 'b',
... 'age':10
... },
... {'name': 'c',
... 'age':15
... },
... {'name': 'd',
... 'age':10
... }]

>>> len([item for item in lst if item['age'] == 10])
3
```

Comment: OP said they want to avoid using loops. This solution does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner:

```
number_of_people = sum( person['age'] == 10 for person in list_of_people)
```